# Where should I source /usr/local/etc/profile from? .bash_profile or /etc/profile?

Tags: bash, shell, etc, conventions

I know that, by default, bash will source `/etc/profile` and `~/.bash_profile`.

Now, suppose I also have machine-specific profile commands in `/usr/local/etc/profile` (involving stuff that's in `/usr/local`, hence I don't want to sully `/etc` with it).

My question: Whose responsibility is it to source `/usr/local/etc/profile` ? Should it be sourced within `~/.bash_profile`, or perhaps the lines:

```
if [ -f /usr/local/etc/profile ]; then
    . /usr/local/etc/profile
fi
```

*should* actually be within `/etc/profile`, since they're valid for any installation of the distribution regardless of what's on the actual machine?

Comment: huh? ", and not also /etc/profile unless that's explicitly sourced from within the home directory's ~/.bash_profile." that seems wrong. /etc/profile is always sourced for login shells!

Comment: A couple of things come to mind: 1) are your users supposed to choose whether/how the content of `/usr/local/etc/profile` may affect them? 2) Existing users will need to edit their shell initialization files if you go for `.bash_profile` (and won't otherwise).

Comment: @MarcusMüller: You're right; see edit.

Answer (score 1):

Conventionally, the right place to put machine-specific login-time initialization is `/etc/profile`. Many Unix variants don't bother much with `/usr/local/etc` if at all, anyway.

Note that for GUI logins, no `profile` file is directly read. However many distributions of X11 arrange to read source `/etc/profile` from the X session initialization. `/usr/local/etc/profile` is not a classic location and would not be sourced.

Many distributions have a directory `/etc/profile.d`, and put code in `/etc/profile` to source the files in `/etc/profile.d`. If your distribution does that, the best place for your machine-specific content would be a machine-specific file in `/etc/profile.d`.

On modern *BSD, `/usr/local` is for packaged software, not for local installation, and there `/usr/local/etc` is for files shipped with a package or their configuration. There the distinction between `/etc` and `/usr/local/etc` is whether the configuration is meant for the base system or for a specific program. `/etc/profile` is a system-wide configuration — you could make a case that if the login shell is a third-party package then its configuration should be in `/usr/local/etc`, but `profile` is not specific to a given shell and applies to `/bin/sh` which is part of the base system. (FreeBSD appears to be inconsistent though: the bash package reads `/usr/local/etc/profile` whereas the zsh package reads `/etc/zprofile`.)

If you (as the administrator) leave it to users to source another file from their `.profile`, that indicates that the customizations in that file are not meant for everyone, only for users who have an unusual need.

Comment: 1. I did not mention the `.d` directories to simplify the question. In fact I'm asking about `/etc/profile.d` files vs. `/usr/local/etc/profile.d` files with a mechanism in` /usr/local/etc/profile` which sources all of the latter. 2. Are you saying that if I've installed a package under `/usr/local`, I should place it's `etc` content, or at least its `etc/profile.d` files, under `/etc` rather than `/usr/local/etc`? How does that make sense?

Comment: @einpoklum *BSD uses `/usr/local/etc` for configuration files for programs in `/usr/local/bin`. On systems where `/usr/local` is for unpackaged software, the tradition is to use `/etc`.

Comment: @einpoklum on your run-of-the-mill Linux distros where `/etc/profile.d` is present, `/etc` is the admin's domain. Packages may put files there, but package management systems do not willy-nilly override modifications. It makes no sense to use something else when that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

> Whose responsibility is it to source `/usr/local/etc/profile`?

If this is supposed to be available by all users then source it from `/etc/profile`. Add those line as you already mentioned into `/etc/profile`

```
[ -f /usr/local/etc/profile ] && source /usr/local/etc/profile
```